# Changing Lighting Depending on Time on Roblox studio

Tags: roblox

I want to change the lighting of my game when its night time. I don't know how I would go about doing this. What I want to know is if I can change the color correction of my game depending on time and how to do so.

```
if game.Lighting.TimeOfDay <= 7:00:00 then
    game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = false
end
```

I've tried that but I don't know where to place it or if it even works.

Comment: You could get the first 2 characters of TimeOfDay (as it is a string), and then use ToNumber to compare it. Also, if you haven’t even *tried* your script, why are you asking here? Just try it.

Comment: Well I have tried it but I couldn't really see if it worked because the output wasn't showing errors and nothing changed. My bad for not saying it well. I did try making the new script with things you told me to do but I don't think I did it right. I don't really know much scripting but what I did end up making was "if game.Lighting.TimeOfDay.ToNumber("7:00:00") then
 game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = false
end" The output said attempt to call nil value. Then when I put it in workspace it doesn't say any errors but just doesn't work. I initially had in startercharacter scripts.

Comment: Is it a LocalScript? LocalScripts don’t work in Workspace.

Comment: I got it to work "if game.Lighting.ClockTime >= 7 then 
 game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = false 
end" Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you select Lighting, there will be a setting in properties that say clock time

Comment: Not what I mean, what I meant was changing things like color correction depending on the time of day. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I made a scritp in workspace

```
if game.Lighting.ClockTime >= 7 then 
    game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = false 
end
```